# Using jQuery to find a html element in a parallel tree path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have this piece of html:

```
<div>
   <a class="target"/>
   <div>
        <a class="target"/>
        <div>
            <hr class="source"/>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to find the closest target from the source, meaning the one where I need to climb the fewest amount of parents. With a binding, I get the source element, that I'll note source. I want to find the second anchor, which is two levels deep, as it's closer to my source hr.

Here's what I have right now is, which works:

```
var target = source
   .parentsUntil(".target").eq(0)
   .find(".target")[0];
```

It seems rather uneffective though, because parentsUntil will test and return too many of the parents. I'd like it to stop on the first parent containing a .target element. Then I feel like calling find after makes jQuery look for target once more while it had already found it before with parentsUntil.

I can think of another solution that would involve iterating over source.parents() and calling find until I have a result but that would still search into branches that have already been explored.

Is there a function in jQuery or a custom algorithm I could leverage to get my result by exploring only the part of the tree that needs to be explored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// starts at the element(s) with the class of
// 'source':
$('.source')
  // finds the closest <div> element that contains
  // an <a> element with the class-name of 'target':
  .closest('div:has("a.target")')
  // finds that contained <a> element with
  // the class of 'target':
  .find('a.target');
```

```js
$('.source').closest('div:has("a.target")').find('a.target').addClass('found');
```

```css
a::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
.found {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="target"></a>
  <div>
    <a class="target"></a>
    <div>
      <hr class="source" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

Comment: It does look better than my current implementation even if it still searches twice for the target (once when calling closest and once when calling find, unless I'm mistaken). If you have an idea to avoid that, I'll take it, thanks

Comment: There isn't really an efficient means of doing that without explicitly traversing up a level and then looking at siblings (or potentially the descendants of those siblings). Given that you want to navigate upwards and find a descendant of that ancestor a double-search is, or seems to be, the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use `.parent()` to select the parent div of `.source` element and use `.prev()`  to get the previous element which is `<a>` in your case

```
$('.source').parent().prev()
```

or you can use

```
$('.source').parent().parent().find('a.target')
```

Comment: That would work for this specific case but not if my closest target was 2 levels above or after the div containing the hr.

Comment: @Friedrik that's why I said (In your case) in my answer .. cause the code will work in your question html structure .. I updated my answer with another code